# I can't draw good lines with the UV texture brush

Tags: uv-image-editor

I want to draw thin and clear lines, but when I tried to, every lines are broken and thier quality is pretty bad. How could I made it work better? I used 1 px line but in the video which i referd, even 30 px brush could make thin lines. I guess that 1 px brush doesn't work good.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the brush parameters in the *UV/Image Editor* tools panel (<kbd>T</kbd> to display).

If you want a continuous line you should use the *Space* stroke method (you can also press <kbd>E</kbd> in the image window to switch form a stroke to another).

Make sure that the *Spacing* value is low enough so that the line is not broken.

To make the line sharp, change its curve (you can add or remove points to give the curve the shape you want), if you select the second one it is pretty sharp.

To save the brush you've created, on the top of the panel, on the right of the brush name, click on the "+" button.

Also good to know, in the image window, <kbd>F</kbd> to increase the *Radius*, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to increase the *Strength*, <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]